# SQL - Finding substring matches within the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with names (string) of parts and subparts, and I would like to get a two column table with the relations between parts and subparts. The relation exists if the name is a substring of another name.

For example, this is what I have:

| Name |
| --- |
| AAA |
| BBB |
| CCC |
| AAA_1 |
| AAA_2 |
| BBB_1 |
| CCC_3 |

And I would like to get this:

| Part | Subpart |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | AAA_1 |
| AAA | AAA_2 |
| BBB | BBB_1 |
| CCC | CCC_3 |

Answer (score 1):

Try Following Query, its give exact output, i try this using like
clause and self join

```
CREATE TABLE SubStrTable 
(
  Name  varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO SubStrTable (Name) VALUES ('AAA');
INSERT INTO SubStrTable (Name) VALUES ('BBB');
INSERT INTO SubStrTable (Name) VALUES ('CCC');
INSERT INTO SubStrTable (Name) VALUES ('AAA_1');
INSERT INTO SubStrTable (Name) VALUES ('AAA_2');
INSERT INTO SubStrTable (Name) VALUES ('BBB_1');
INSERT INTO SubStrTable (Name) VALUES ('CCC_3');



Select T1.Name As Part,T2.Name As Subpart From SubStrTable T1
Left Join SubStrTable T2
ON T2.Name Like  T1.Name + '_[0-9]'
Where T1.Name Not Like  + '%_[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try a self join here:

```sql
SELECT t1.Name AS Part, t2.Name AS Subpart
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.Name LIKE t1.Name + '[_]%'
WHERE t1.Name NOT LIKE '%[_]%'
ORDER BY t1.Name, t2.Name;
```